# Citrix Workspace - no audio options, microphone not working

Tags: microphone, citrix

I am trying to enable my microphone in Citrix Workspace for Linux:

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/whats-new.html

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/get-started.html#preferences

I can connect with an ICA file, but am unable to add an account, so I am unable to follow the steps for me to configure the microphone.

Is there another way to configure Citrix Workspaces to use my embedded microphone, or if I plug in a USB one to use that?

Comment: Even after updating to Ubuntu 21.04 and Citrix Workspace app 2104, I have no improvement here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a detailed guide how to make Citrix Workspace and MS Teams in it work with Ubuntu host:

## Instructions

### Step 1. Download and install Citrix Workspace for Linux

- Download .deb package from here: https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html
- Install with:

  ```
  dpkg -i icaclient_xx.y.z._amd64.deb
  ```

### Step 2. Trust third-party certificate (optional)

*Some organizations use certificates from authorities not present in Citrix Workspace distribution. In my case it was QuoVadis, following steps make it registered with Citrix client.*

```bash
# Download the certificate in PEM format
curl https://www.quovadisglobal.com/wp-content/files/media/qvrca2g3_pem.pem \
  -o "qvrca2g3_pem.crt"

# Make sure the CA certificate file is owned by root user and group, and
# it has `-rw-r--r--` or `644` as the file permissions
sudo chmod -v 644 "qvrca2g3_pem.crt"
sudo chown -v root:root "qvrca2g3_pem.crt"

# Copy the certificate to the keystore
sudo cp -v "qvrca2g3_pem.crt" \
  "/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/"

# Rehash contents of the keystore
sudo "/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash"
```

### Step 3. Fix detecting audio devices in Microsoft Teams

- Install libc++1-12 and libunwind-12 on the local ubuntu (22.04) host:

  ```bash
  source "/etc/os-release"

  # Commented out since apt will complain
  # curl -fsSL https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add

  # Recommended solution
  curl -fsSL https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key \
  | gpg --output  "gpg-pub-gpg-llvm-snapshot.gpg" --dearmor
  sudo mv -v "gpg-pub-gpg-llvm-snapshot.gpg" "/usr/share/keyrings/"

  # Commented out since apt will complain
  # sudo add-apt-repository \
  #  "deb http://apt.llvm.org/${UBUNTU_CODENAME}/ llvm-toolchain-${UBUNTU_CODENAME} main"

  # Recommended solution
  echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/gpg-pub-gpg-llvm-snapshot.gpg] http://apt.llvm.org/${UBUNTU_CODENAME}/ llvm-toolchain-${UBUNTU_CODENAME} main" \
  | sudo tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm-org-${UBUNTU_CODENAME}.list"

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install libc++1-12 libunwind-12
  ```

Sourcing `/etc/os-release` should provide the `UBUNTU_CODENAME` variable. If it does not work you need to replace it with the respective codename, jammy here in this case for Ubuntu 22.04.

### Step 4. Enable pulseaudio support in Citrix

- Navigate to the `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/config` folder and open the `module.ini` file as root.
- Go to the `[ClientAudio]` section and add or modify so you have the following entry:

  ```
  AudioRedirectionV4=True
  ```
- Restart the session for the changes to take effect.

### Step 5. Enable microphone in Citrix

- Navigate to the `~/.ICAClient` folder and open the `wfclient.ini` file.
- Go to the `[WFClient]` section and add the following entry:

  ```
  AllowAudioInput=True
  ```
- Restart the session for the changes to take effect.

## Opinions and more tricks

Making audio work is the most complicated part - sometimes you need to unplug your USB audio device from linux machine and plug it back while having the Citrix connection up. Also **pavucontrol** tool may be helpful in configuring which device should be used by Citrix for playback and recording. Install pavucontrol with:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Video worked for me “out of the box”, without any hacking required.

Some more tricks:

- Set up automatically choosing the right audio device as a default playback and recording source in Windows when starting Citrix session: on your linux host goto `~/.ICAClient` folder and edit `wfclient.ini` file by adding `[ClientAudio]` section at the bottom of the file. Put one line in that section `AudioDevice=\<Jabra Link 370\>`. Replace "Jabra Link 370" with the name of your device, you can get the name by launching pavucontrol on linux and looking at the Configuration pane.
- Many users will be using Gnome so the following should make things easier working with keyboard shortcuts (via [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/citrix#Troubleshooting)):

  ```bash
  gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-grab-access-rules "['Wfica']"
  gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.wayland xwayland-allow-grabs true
  ```

Comment: I got rid from instability in automatically choosing the right audio device as a default playback and recording source in Windows when starting Citrix session. For this on your linux host goto ~/.ICAClient folder and edit wfclient.ini file by adding [ClientAudio] section at the bottom of the file. Put one line in that section AudioDevice=\<Jabra Link 370\>. Replace "Jabra Link 370" with the name of your device, you can get the name by launching pavucontrol on linux and looking at the Configuration pane.

Comment: My last info on apt-key was that it will be deprecated and removed soon, but apparently it is still in 22.04. I tried to streamline some of the parts and added a reference to the ArchWiki. It's quite frustrating that one hits so many road bumps with the default configuration on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled audio input in the wfclient.ini?
add this

```
[WFClient]
AllowAudioInput=True
```

The wflient.ini file can be found under ~/.ICAClient

Answer (score 0):

This is very helpful for me, but for Ubuntu 23.10
For those on Ubuntu 23.10, replace 12 with 17. The other steps were not required to be done by me.

```
sudo apt-get install libc++1-17 libunwind-17
```